# DAX: Average of same months across multiple years

Tags: powerbi, dax, moving-average

I am attempting to create something similar to a rolling average in power BI, however this calculation averages for a rolling period (say 5 years) using only a single month at a time.

I have sum total figures for 12 months for each year for 5 years in a table with the dates.

Any ideas on how to create a summary measure or table that will calculate this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you looked into time intelligence formulas? What does your data model look like? Are you using a separate calendar table?

Comment: We have the data in both pivoted and unpivoted forms, so that's not really the issue. Can use a separate calendar table, I know how to set that up no problem. The idea is to get these averages and then perform a net change across the months from month to month and graph that. So I'm thinking I need to get it into a table and not just create a measure.

Comment: Perhaps one way would be to grab the relative timeframes using variables, then perform the calc. but then I am left with a bunch of disparate months, not a series of data. I want to end with a series of net changes I can apply.

Comment: To many reasons why your dax doesn't work. Just add you tables samples result sample and dax you've tried to the question and, I believe, you will get ideas about that.